# How Do I Set Symbols Down After Matching

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

My Problem is when my symbols become match I want my symbols to fall, ( the top symbols that have matches on Reels)

my Reference was during match the Slot Script inside my Slots become Null (None Symbol Item) which is
the reference of my Symbol item prefab that inherit the script of SymbolItem data.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using NaughtyAttributes;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] [ReadOnly] private SymbolItem m_SymbolItem;

    [SerializeField] private EffectHandler m_EffectHandler;

    public bool isWild;

    #region GETTER AND SETTER
    public SymbolItem GetSymbolItem => m_SymbolItem;
    public void SetSymbolItem(SymbolItem i_SymbolItem) => m_SymbolItem = i_SymbolItem;
    public void SetSymbolItemToNull() => m_SymbolItem = null;
    public  EffectHandler GetEffectHandler() => m_EffectHandler;
    #endregion
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using DG.Tweening;
using NaughtyAttributes;
using System;

public class Reel : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("REFERENCES")]
    [SerializeField] private List<Slot> m_Slots;
    [SerializeField] private List<Slot> m_DummySlots;
    [SerializeField] private List<Slot> m_OriginalSlots;

    #region MANAGER REFERENCES
    private PoolManager m_PoolManager => GameManager.PoolManager; // get only reference from PoolManager Script to be Enqueue and Dequeue
    #endregion

    #region GETTERS
    public List<Slot> GetOriginalSlot() => m_OriginalSlots;
    public List<Slot> GetSlots() => m_Slots; // TODAY
    #endregion
    private Vector3 _originPosition;
    public Vector3 GetOriginPosition => _originPosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        _originPosition = transform.localPosition;
    }

    [Button]
    public void Spin(float i_Speed) // this is where the Spin of the Object Pooling.
    {
        SymbolItem _symbolItem = m_Slots[m_Slots.Count - 1].GetSymbolItem;

        for (int i = m_Slots.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            
            m_Slots[i].SetSymbolItem(m_Slots[i - 1].GetSymbolItem); // Move data to the previous slot
        }
        m_Slots[0].SetSymbolItemToNull();
        m_PoolManager.Enqueue(_symbolItem);

        SymbolItem newObject = m_PoolManager.Dequeue(); // symbolitem which is the symbols, then dequeue which reused the 1st index of the pool that we put in the 1st index of SymbolsOnReel and set active to true.
        newObject.transform.SetParent(transform); // we set the new object from the pool to be parent of this gameobject which is the (Reel[i])
        newObject.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(m_Slots[0].transform.position, Quaternion.identity); // we set it at first index of m_slotposition and its transform and rotation.
        m_Slots[0].SetSymbolItem(newObject);

        for (int i = 0; i < m_Slots.Count; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            if (index == 0)
            {
                m_Slots[index].GetSymbolItem.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            m_Slots[index].GetSymbolItem.transform.DOLocalMove(m_Slots[index].transform.localPosition, i_Speed)
                .SetEase(Ease.Linear)
                .OnComplete(() =>
                {
                    m_Slots[index].GetSymbolItem.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                });
        }

    }

    public void SetParentToReel()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < m_Slots.Count; i++)
        {
            SymbolItem symbol = m_PoolManager.Dequeue(); // instantiate from Objectpooling at Random range symbols from the start. (from here we Instantantiating from the start
            symbol.transform.SetParent(transform); // we set the transform to parent
            symbol.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(m_Slots[i].transform.position, Quaternion.identity); // we sert the transform localposition and rotation (Local Position from Parent)
            m_Slots[i].SetSymbolItem(symbol);          
        }
        
    }
}
```

my Script for my Reel
each Reel have this Reel script so total of (total of 6 reels)

so in my panelgame is 6x6. of symbols.

```
private void EnqueueSetToNull(List<Slot> i_slots)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i_slots.Count; j++)
        {
            m_PoolManager.Enqueue(i_slots[j].GetSymbolItem);
            i_slots[j].SetSymbolItemToNull();
        }
        StartFallSymbols(i_slots);
    }
```

after i enqueue and set the symbolitem to null in a match slot.
i call the StartFallSymbols function
where my symbol should fall in the null slots.

I use DOTween for this.

Comment: Please include `StartFallSymbols` method.  I suspect it is a coroutine, and needs start coroutine to function.